# Incorrect spell check results

Tags: firefox, gedit, bug-reporting, spell-checking

Firefox and Gedit (at least) are checking spelling wrongly. Which package should I file a bug against?

For some time I've had issues with spell checking in Firefox. I hadn't bothered with them since I didn't want to clear my profile and do all the other necessary troubleshooting steps. I've seen [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/enchant/+bug/254223) but it seems to be languishing because it's missing key information.

## Here are my symptoms:

1. In Firefox, the spell checker only underlines words containing apostrophes (all of them) and deems every other word to be correct. Here's a screenshot:

   [image]
2. In Gedit, words appear to end at apostrophes. But, the problem is less serious as the following two screenshots show:

   ---

   [image]

   ---

   [image]

   ---

## Other information

- This is a fresh install of Quantal with a clean `$HOME`. However, I've experienced the Firefox issue for at least a year, perhaps longer. The Gedit issue I only noticed in the course of testing the [bug I referenced earlier](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/enchant/+bug/254223).
- I experience the Firefox issue on a different machine running Precise. I have not tested the other machine with Gedit.
- My locale is `en_US.UTF-8` and my keyboard layout is Korean (hardware and software).
- I don't know whether these two issues are related or separate problems.
- I care a lot about the Firefox problem. I don't care very much about the Gedit issue.

Comment: I am using US keyboard. In Firefox and Chrome, spellcheck flags "smoe" and does not flag "isn't"' Thus there is no problem. However, in Gedit, "isn't" is flagged as well. So the problem is reproducable in Gedit.

Comment: @user68186: Perhaps it would be more proper to say that you can't reproduce the problem. It *does* exist for me on two different machines.

Comment: I see you care more about the Firefox than about the Gedit issue.I missed the last bullet point of the question. Sorry.

Comment: Did someone add a bunch of words to the dictionary can you check the contents of `~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxxx.default/persdict.dat` you need to manually navigate there since "xxxxxxxx" is a random string of letters.

Comment: yeah, known bug in gedit https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/36227 , not sure about Firefox, what version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would file the bug against firefox and gedit. Unfortunately you will need to sign up to file a bug.

This guide tells you how to file a bug against firefox. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Bug_writing_guidelines. I would give them a link to the question as it has a lot of information they would need.

For gedit, go to https://bugzilla.gnome.org/.
I hope this helps.

Oh yes, see if this works: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/united-states-english-spellche/. It is a dictionary.

Comment: But without doing a bit more work, the chance that the bug will be fixed is almost nil.

Comment: Please state how YOU would file a bug report

Comment: I already know *how* to file a bug report. The question is filing one that's sufficiently useful that it has a chance of actually getting fixed.